# Dollar $ symbol in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a couple of collections that has a string like this.

This is a cool stock. $AAPL. Let's buy it.
This is a cool stock. $MSFT. Let's buy it.
This is a cool stock. $GOOG. Let's buy it.

How do I find the APPL one.

i use something like this db.collection_name.find(fieldname: /$AAPL/) but it doesn't like the dollar symbol. If i run it without the $ in it, it works fine. But I only want the result when the $AAPL is in the text.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A complete C# example:

```
// sample class with a property that could contain the sample string 
// in your example, "This is a cool stock. $MSFT"
public class Talk {
  public string Message { get; set; } 
}

var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
var server = client.GetServer();
var database = server.GetDatabase("stocktalk");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Talk>("talk");

var query = Query<Talk>.EQ(m => m.Message, 
                           new BsonRegularExpression(@"\$MSFT"));
// get all of the Talk objects that match
var matches = collection.FindAs<Talk>(query);
```

Also note that this is a very inefficient query in general as it would need to search through **all** documents in the collection to find a match. You might want to consider storing the stock ticker symbols in a distinct array property as part of the document and using `$in` to find them (you could then use an index for example and it would be very fast to find matching strings):

```
public class Talk {
  public string Message { get; set; } 
  public string[] TickerSymbols { get; set; }
}

var query = Query<Talk>.In(m => m.TickerSymbols, new string[]{"$MSFT"});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$` is a special character in regular expressions; it matches the end of the original string.

To match a literal `$` character, you need to escape it with a backslash:

```
db.collection_name.find(fieldname: /\$AAPL/)
```